# MySQL inserting year in date as 2000 and not 1900

Tags: php, mysql, csv, strtotime

I am fetching the date value from CSV which gives value as "2/20/1967". But while inserting this value in table it is showing 2067-02-20.

I am using strtotime() to convert the date value in proper format

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob))
```

Comment: What's the format of the date in the CSV file? That is: what are the contents of `$dob`? Bear in mind that [`strtotime()` maps two-digit years to the range 1970 -> 2069](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes).

Comment: In CSV the value is "20-Feb-67". But it outputs in php code as 02/20/2067

Comment: Exactly. As per my link above, 67 (on its own, rather than *1967* or *2067*) is mapped to 2067 in `strtotime()`. You will need to write a custom date parser if you expect it to map differently.